# VaryByQueryKeys not working with parameters

Tags: caching, asp.net-core-mvc, varybyquerykeys

My asp.net core mvc app doesn't always rerun the controller when I change the value of my parameter. It just returns the previous cache. I thought VaryByQueryKeys was meant to address this.

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByQueryKeys = new string[] { "widthHeight" }, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any)]
        [Route("/{widthHeight}")]
        public IActionResult Index(string widthHeight)
        {
```

Comment: Any update? Does my reply help you?

Comment: Hey, thanks. It was actually working, returning the cached view. I just didn't notice because I wasn't passing the values I was changing into the view. When I started doing that it was all fine. Stupid error. Thanks again!

Comment: If you feel my reply has helped you, please mark it as answer. So that other folks who faces the same error will find the answer more easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you use chrome by entering the URL (e.g. [www.example.com/abcd/index.html](http://www.example.com/abcd/index.html)) directly into the address bar or use F5 to refresh the page, the chrome will always send the   `Cache-Control: max-age=0` header.

This is the reason why your response cache is not working.

To solve this issue, you should use another browser to test like IE11 or you could set a hyperlink in your application like below:

```
<a href="https://localhost:44374/?widthHeight=aaaa">aaa</a>
```

If you click this hyperlink, you will find the cache will work.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, none of the followings produce the expected cached-by-unique-parameters-values:

`VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "*" }`

`VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "searchparam" }`

given `public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromQuery] string searchparam)`

**Solution** is prefix it with a `$`, that is
`VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "$searchparam" }`